# Drawing text onto an NSImage in a loop - but how do I clear the cache?

Tags: objective-c, caching, nsimage

I have an NSTimer calling a method once a second, which checks a simple integer value, called 'total'. This value is then drawn on top of an NSImage and displayed on the screen.

```
NSImage *totalIcon = [NSImage imageNamed:@"round_red"];
[totalIcon lockFocus];
NSString *totalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", total];
[totalString drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint withAttributes:nil];
[totalIcon unlockFocus];
```

My expectation was that on every iteration, totalIcon would start afresh and take on the original round_red image. But it actually appears to be doing some caching. So I checked the NSImage reference and saw that I could do this:

```
[totalIcon setCacheMode:NSImageCacheNever];
```

But this seems to have no effect because on every new iteration, totalIcon's value is set to a modified round_red, which includes the previous values written on it. I wanted to start with a clean image each time.

What am I doing wrong? Is it being cached somewhere else? If anyone is kind enough to help, I would value answers that are simple over the most efficient, as I would like to understand my code and will optimize it later, if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use initWithContentsOfFile: to create your image instead of imageNamed:. That method does not cause the image to be cached.

```
NSImage *totalIcon = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"round_red" ofType:@"jpg"]]; // change @"jpg" to whatever is appropriate for your image file
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work initially, it was returning nil each time. Then I realized it was because my image was in the Images.xcassets asset catalog. So, I removed it from the catalog and it now works, thanks so much. One quick follow-up - will this break automatically handling of 2x images or will the 2x image still be picked up as appropriate? I can't test as I'm not on a retina machine.

Comment: @Gavin, it should work fine for 2x images as long as you give the method the correct file name.

Comment: Thanks again, I spent several hours on this and you solved it for me.